# How to set the restamp property on a dom-if

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I wish to remove and create a dom depending on a polymer dom-if. To do this I will have to use the restamp property. Given the code below, is this the proper way of using the restamp property

### user_page.html:

```
<dom-module id="user-page">
  <template>
    All users will see this:
    <div>{{user.name}}</div>
    <template restamp is="dom-if" if="{{user.isAdmin}}">
      Only admins will see this.
      <div>{{user.secretAdminStuff}}</div>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

### user_page.dart:

```
@PolymerRegister('user-page')
class UserPage extends PolymerElement {
  UserPage.created() : super.created();

  @property
  User user;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is how you set a boolean property. 
See also the code in the related unit test https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/c2b7c31b8e176a642bbf81f422d19091ed80d5e3/test/smoke/dom-if.html#L39